# Rigorous Definition of Resistors in Parallel when Circuit is Defined as a Graph

Tags: circuit-analysis, resistors, parallel, math, graph

Sometimes electric circuits -at least the ones consisting of voltage sources, resistors, inductors, and capacitors- are defined rigorously as a graph, such as done [here](https://johncarlosbaez.wordpress.com/2013/04/03/network-theory-part-27/).

Given the definition of a circuit as a graph, would the following be a correct definition of two resistors \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$ being in parallel?:

**Definition:** a ***path*** \$p\$ is a finite collection of edges \$\{e^1,\ldots,e^n\}\$ with \$t(e^k)=s(e^{k+1})\$. We write \$s(p) := s(e^1)\$ and \$t(p) := t(e^n)\$.

**Definition:** we say the resistors \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$ are in ***parallel*** if there are paths \$p\$ and \$q\$ such that

- \$s(p) = t(R_1)\$ and \$t(p) = s(R_2)\$,
- \$s(q) = t(R_2)\$ and \$t(q) = s(R_1)\$,
- None of the edges in \$p\$ or \$q\$ are voltage sources, resistors, inductors, or capacitors.

Comment: I didn't see what I would call a graph in your link.

Comment: @Andyaka There isn't, there. But there are some references there that do move quickly in such direction ([example](https://westy31.home.xs4all.nl/Electric.html).)

Comment: @Andyaka graphs are mentioned multiple times; under my interpretation, circuits are defined in terms of graphs as of line "So, define a **graph** to consist of two functions \$s,t:E\to N\$". So that a circuits is a graph together with the \$I_e,V_e\$ functions complying with certain properties such as KVL and KCL.

Comment: @Sam , I think you need to spend some time framing your question here (or anywhere.) Not just finger-pointing or hand-waving in some direction. Topological equivalence may, for example, require framing with respect to the black box found in Figure 4.30 in Section 4.6 of **Graph Theory and Its Engineering Applications** by *Wai-Kai Chen*. Where you pick off points in a graph matters as to whether they are equivalent. Section 4.6 might also be a good segue, working backwards from there to Chapter 3, in framing your question better. Starting with the general form he mentions as \$I=Y\:V\$.

Comment: @Sam The black box makes possible the idea using transfer functions for equivalence. Also, there are graphs. And then there are graphs. I tend to visualize a circuit as a fully connected graph where the right nullspace of the directed graph has only one vector in it. And you would still need to pick off a pair of nodes on one side and a pair of nodes on the other side, I think. But I don't know what definitions you would choose. So again I think you need to spend time framing your question. You write far, far, far too little for my tastes. You need to take the leads, I think.

Comment: @Sam I also think that the [this MIT open courseware PDF page](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/18-06sc-linear-algebra-fall-2011/resources/mit18_06scf11_ses1-12sum/) uses a simple Wheatstone bridge (also used in Chen's book) as a nice segue and also provides meaning to the rowspace, columnspace, right and left nullspaces for a connected graph, showing KCL and Ohm's Law in stark relief there. This is the kind of thing I would expect from you (and more) in order to properly frame up your question. "Parallel" and "series" can be worked into that, I believe, with clarity. But it needs framing.

Comment: In "applied graph theory" by W. K. Chen, there is the definition of circuit (Definition 1.8) and that is: A closed edge train in which all the nodes i₁ , i₂,...ik-1 are distinct in this case i₁= ik is called a circuit of length k-1. It follows that the parallel of n elements is a closed edge train of length 1.